# Knapsack problem or permutation? How to solve my problem?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase

Hello hopefully someone can help me or atleast give me the view in the right direction.

I have an Array with a size of 100 to 500 items in it. Each item has the attributes name(string), weight(float), points(float), position(int). The max weight is not a fixed number, positions are (1,2,3,4,5) each positions need to be filled. Each items can only be used once. The outcome should be the 15 combinations with the max points of 7 items.

As far as i get my laptop crashed because of full memory.

I tried a solution in typescript to use firebase.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
export const potItems = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    let possibleItems: any[] = [];
    let counter: number = 0;
    const items = [
        { name: "James Harden", position: "PG", weight: 15.9, points: 62.63 },
        { name: "Russell Westbrook", position: "PG", weight: 14.9, points: 56.12 },
        { name: "LeBron James", position: "SF", weight: 15.9, points: 55.67 },
        { name: "Bradley Beal", position: "SG", weight: 14.8, points: 52.69 },
        { name: "Anthony Davis", position: "PF", weight: 14.6, points: 52.16 },
        { name: "Damian Lillard", position: "PG", weight: 13.5, points: 49.34 },
        { name: "Nikola Vucevic", position: "C", weight: 12.9, points: 47.97 },
        { name: "Domantas Sabonis", position: "PF", weight: 12.8, points: 47.6 },
        { name: "Kristaps Porzingis", position: "PF", weight: 13.5, points: 47.18 },
        { name: "Andre Drummond", position: "C", weight: 12.2, points: 45.97 },
        { name: "Kawhi Leonard", position: "SF", weight: 13.2, points: 46.08 },
        { name: "Hassan Whiteside", position: "C", weight: 12.2, points: 45.83 },
        { name: "DeAndre Ayton", position: "C", weight: 11.8, points: 45.57 },
        { name: "Paul George", position: "SF", weight: 11.1, points: 43.8 },
        { name: "D'Angelo Russell", position: "PG", weight: 11.5, points: 44.0 },
        { name: "Julius Randle", position: "PF", weight: 11.3, points: 42.46 },
        { name: "DeMar DeRozan", position: "SG", weight: 11.2, points: 40.6 },
        { name: "Coby White", position: "PG", weight: 10.5, points: 37.85 },
        { name: "Ricky Rubio", position: "PG", weight: 11.1, points: 37.83 },
        { name: "Robert Covington", position: "SF", weight: 9.1, points: 37.26 },
        { name: "James Harden", position: "PG", weight: 15.9, points: 62.63 },
        { name: "Russell Westbrook", position: "PG", weight: 14.9, points: 56.12 },
        { name: "LeBron James", position: "SF", weight: 15.9, points: 55.67 },
        { name: "Bradley Beal", position: "SG", weight: 14.8, points: 52.69 },
        { name: "Anthony Davis", position: "PF", weight: 14.6, points: 52.16 },
        { name: "Damian Lillard", position: "PG", weight: 13.5, points: 49.34 },
        { name: "Nikola Vucevic", position: "C", weight: 12.9, points: 47.97 },
        { name: "Domantas Sabonis", position: "PF", weight: 12.8, points: 47.6 },
        { name: "Kristaps Porzingis", position: "PF", weight: 13.5, points: 47.18 },
        { name: "Andre Drummond", position: "C", weight: 12.2, points: 45.97 },
        { name: "Kawhi Leonard", position: "SF", weight: 13.2, points: 46.08 },
        { name: "Hassan Whiteside", position: "C", weight: 12.2, points: 45.83 },
        { name: "DeAndre Ayton", position: "C", weight: 11.8, points: 45.57 },
        { name: "Paul George", position: "SF", weight: 11.1, points: 43.8 },
        { name: "D'Angelo Russell", position: "PG", weight: 11.5, points: 44.0 },
        { name: "Julius Randle", position: "PF", weight: 11.3, points: 42.46 },
        { name: "DeMar DeRozan", position: "SG", weight: 11.2, points: 40.6 },
        { name: "Coby White", position: "PG", weight: 10.5, points: 37.85 },
        { name: "Ricky Rubio", position: "PG", weight: 11.1, points: 37.83 },
        { name: "Robert Covington", position: "SF", weight: 9.1, points: 37.26 }
    ];

        for (let index0 = 0; index0 < items.length; index0++) {
          for (let index1 = 0; index1 < items.length; index1++) {
            if (index1 == index0) {
              break;
            }
            for (let index2 = 0; index2 < items.length; index2++) {
              if (index2 == index0 || index2 == index1) {
                break;
              }
              for (let index3 = 0; index3 < items.length; index3++) {
                if (index3 == index0 || index3 == index1 || index3 == index2) {
                  break;
                }
                for (let index4 = 0; index4 < items.length; index4++) {
                  if (
                    index4 == index0 ||
                    index4 == index1 ||
                    index4 == index2 ||
                    index4 == index3
                  ) {
                    break;
                  }
                  for (let index5 = 0; index5 < items.length; index5++) {
                    if (
                      index5 == index0 ||
                      index5 == index1 ||
                      index5 == index2 ||
                      index5 == index3 ||
                      index5 == index4
                    ) {
                      break;
                    }
                    for (let index6 = 0; index6 < items.length; index6++) {
                      if (
                        index6 == index0 ||
                        index6 == index1 ||
                        index6 == index2 ||
                        index6 == index3 ||
                        index6 == index4 ||
                        index6 == index5
                      ) {
                        break;
                      }
                      let item: number[] = [];
                        item.push(index0);
                        item.push(index1);
                        item.push(index2);
                        item.push(index3);
                        item.push(index4);
                        item.push(index5);
                        item.push(index6);
                        item.sort((a, b) => a - b);
                        counter++;
                        possibleItems.push(counter);
                        console.log("item " + counter + ": " + item);

                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        response.send("All items: " + possibleItems);
});
```

The items here are just an example how they could look

thanks for your help

Comment: You are not adequately describing the problem you are trying to solve. `The outcome should be the 15 combinations with the max value of 7 items.` - 15 combinations of what?  What is a "max value" ?

Comment: Running as a firebase function won't help you much if the algorithm isn't up to par; there'll still be a memory and time limit.

Comment: Well i changed value to points. So i need the 15 best point combinations of 7 items

Answer (score 0):

So, you have 7 positions to fill to maximize the sum of points?

Group your items by position, sort each group by points.

Now you can pick combinations of *top* positions in each group, to get maximum points.

Since you have hundreds of items and need only 15 top combinations, you will probably never look at most items after the sorting, and will only juggle the top few in each group.

I don't know what is your measure to choose the 15 combinations. If you only maximize their summary points, you can choose whatever you want. If you want to make combinations more even (each has items with smaller dispersion of points within the combination, or smaller dispersion of summary points among combinations), you might want to add more limitations.

I think something like [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) can be helpful in this case, because you are optimizing a linear target function (a sum).

Comment: My problem here is that i also only have a specific amount of weight i can use. So asume we have 6 items selected its possible that i could better delete item 6 aand take two other because the have combined a better outcome of points. Thats the problem why i cant sort them and take best positions.